# UIWebView website when refreshed moves down - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Whenever I reload the website in the UIWebView used in my app, the website moves down. I do not have an idea as to why this is happening, as when I go on the mobile version of the website in Safari, the website does not scroll down.

*Below is the code for the UIWebView:*

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD
import Canvas

class WebViewHome: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var WebViewContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var WebViewTst: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var animView: CSAnimationView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Home"

    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://gunnoracle.com/")
    WebViewTst.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)

    let topSpace = -190
    let bottomSpace = -3045
    let leftSpace = -40
    let rightSpace = -40
    WebViewTst.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: CGFloat(topSpace), left: CGFloat(leftSpace), bottom: CGFloat(bottomSpace), right: CGFloat(rightSpace))
    WebViewTst.scrollView.bounces = false

    WebViewTst.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    WebViewTst.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

    WebViewTst.delegate = self



}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    self.revealViewController().delegate = self

}

func revealController(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!, didMoveTo position: FrontViewPosition) {

    if(revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.right){


        animView.isHidden = true


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            self.WebViewTst.layer.zPosition = 1
            self.WebViewTst.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -65);
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        })

    }

}
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    switch navigationType {

    case .linkClicked:

        let topSpace = -170
        let bottomSpace = -2840
        let leftSpace = -40
        let rightSpace = -40

        animView.startCanvasAnimation()
        WebViewTst.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: CGFloat(topSpace), left: CGFloat(leftSpace), bottom: CGFloat(bottomSpace), right: CGFloat(rightSpace))
        WebViewTst.scrollView.bounces = false

        WebViewTst.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
        WebViewTst.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

        WebViewTst.delegate = self

    default:
        break
    }
    return true
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")
    SVProgressHUD.setDefaultStyle(SVProgressHUDStyle.dark)
    SVProgressHUD.setRingThickness(1.0)
    NSLog("Webview has started loading")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    NSLog("Webview has successfully loaded")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: How are you reloading the web view? Does this happen on the first load or every load?

Comment: @MatthewCawley This happens on every load and I use the toolbar reload button connected to the UIWebView to reload the webpage

Comment: what happen after mask `SVProgressHUD.dismiss()`  in **webViewDidFinishLoad**?

Comment: @JackyShek that just dismisses the loading indicator for the website when it is loaded

Comment: I know. I have used this tools before. I am asking you that did the webview scroll after you mask it.

Comment: The WebView just scrolls automatically down a little bit each time the webpage is reloaded

Comment: Looking at the code, I can't see anything obvious to adjust the position. My only thought would be on the content offset of the scroll view when you reload. Does the issue happen if you remove the edge insets?

Comment: @MatthewCawley oh that makes much more sense. I was wondering if there was a way to counteract this possibly?

Comment: if the edge insets are a requirement, you can counteract any effect by manually adjusting the scroll content offset as -edgeInset.top. However, it would be a bit more complex as you would need to constantly monitor the scroll position as the moment you scroll, the effect of the edge inset will kick back in. 

I could give you a bit more advice if I could see what effect you was trying to achieve with the edge inset.

Comment: @MatthewCawley could you provide an answer showing how to do this. I could call the content offset code every time the page reloads

Comment: I'm going to add an answer below so you can see the code.

Comment: @MatthewCawley Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a follow up to the comments under the question.

**Note that this code is not tested so should only be used as a guide.**

To counter the content inset at the top and maintain scrolling position you can use code similar to

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat currentYOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat topIntest = scrollView.contentInset.top;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, currentYOffset - topIntest);
}
```

Without seeing your exact project and the expected visual output it is hard to give a perfect answer.

Ideally, you should approach this solution slightly differently. Your code above is using a fixed `contentInset` which tells me that you need your page to have a specific padding in order to look right. What you should really do to ensure that performance is maintained at the highest level, is to implement that padding into the web page that you are loading.

If you have access to the web page source code, using the CSS padding style on the body tag to replicate the spacing/padding/alignment that you want.

If you do not have access to the web page source code, you can alternatively load the web page to a string using

NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"http://example.com" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

You could then inject your own style into the HTML.

There are many ways of doing this, one example is:

```
    NSURL *contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    //load content to string
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:contentURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    //create css style to inject
    NSString *paddingCSS = @"<style> body { margin-top: -190px; margin-left:-40px; margin-right:-40px; margin-bottom:-3045px } </style></head>";

    //inject the string just before the </head> tag
    [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</head>" withString:paddingCSS options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSRangeFromString(content)];

    //load the webview using the content string.
    //Set the baseURL to ensure relative links etc. still work
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:contentURL];
```